# React Frontend is not receiving backend Socket.io emitted signals

Tags: reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io, mern

I learned socket.io a few days ago and since I have been trying to build a global chat app. I have perfectly set up the backend as well as frontend but for some reason my frontend code isn't receiving the emitted signals from the backend, I checked the backend and yes the Signals are being passed over to the backend. Here's the Code, I will share the server index.js, redux slice, & also the frontend code which sends the request.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import http from 'http';
import dt from 'dotenv';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js';
import {dbConnect} from './config/db.js'
import {errorHandler} from './middlewares/errorMiddleware.js'
const dotenv = dt.config();
import MSG from './models/messageModel.js';
const PORT = process.env.NODE_PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);
dbConnect();

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors : {
        origin : "http://localhost:5173",
        methods : ["GET","POST"]
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('conn_made', async() => {
        const messages = await MSG.find();
        socket.emit('initload', {msg : messages});
    })

    socket.on('post', async(data) => {
        const message = await MSG.create(data);
        socket.emit('updatemsg', message);
    })
});

app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);

app.use(errorHandler);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The Server is running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

This is the Index.js.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');

const initState = {
    messages : [],
    isLoading : false
}

export const messageSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'message',
    initialState : initState,
    reducers : {
        resetmsg : (state) => {
            state.messages = [];
            state.isLoading = false;
        },
        addInit : (state,action) => {
            state.isLoading = false;
            console.log(action.payload);
        },
        connect : (state) => {
            socket.emit('conn_made');
            state.isLoading = true;
        },
        post : (state,action) => {
            socket.emit('post', action.payload);
        },
        receive : (state,action) => {
            state.messages.push(action.payload);
        }
    }
});

export const {resetmsg,addInit,connect,post,receive} = messageSlice.actions;
export default messageSlice.reducer;
```

This is the redux slice that emits some signals.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {FaSignOutAlt, FaShare} from 'react-icons/fa';
import {logout} from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
import {resetmsg , addInit , connect , post , receive } from '../features/messages/messageSlice';

const Mainchat = () => {
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  socket.on('initload', (data) => {
    const {msg} = data;
    dispatch(addInit(msg));
  })

  socket.on('updatemsg', (data) => {
    dispatch(receive(data));
  })

  const handleConnect = () => {
    dispatch(connect());
    setConnected(true);
  }

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    await dispatch(logout());
    dispatch(resetmsg());
    navigate('/login');
  }

  const onSend = () => {
    const msg = {user : user._id , text : text};
    dispatch(post(msg))
    setText("");
  }

  return (
    <section className='container flex flex-col p-4 mt-16 h-full w-[40vw] border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg'>
      <div className='flex flex-row justify-between mb-5'>
        <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold'>{connected ? "Connected." : "Disconnected."}</h1>
        <button onClick={handleLogout}><FaSignOutAlt /></button>
      </div>
      {connected ? (
        <div className='flex flex-col space-y-2'>
          <div className='h-[400px] border-y-2 overflow-y-scroll'>
          
          </div>
          <div className='flex flex-row justify-between'>
            <input value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} className='w-96 border-2 border-black py-1 px-2 rounded-lg' type='text' placeholder='Type your Message...' />
            <button onClick={onSend}><FaShare/></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleConnect}>Connect</button>
      )}
      
    </section>
  )
}

export default Mainchat
```

This is the frontend Code. I can't seem to find the issue anyhow, When I click 'Connect', it actually does emit the signal to the backend but the signal emitted from the backend is not read.

I can't seem to find the issue anyhow, When I click 'Connect', it actually does emit the signal to the backend but the signal emitted from the backend is not read.